# Send a request with form answers to an API REST from Liferay WorkFlow

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I'm trying to send a request to a REST API when a submitted form is approved by the people designed on the WorkFlow. I intend to send all form answers to a REST API that will add all the answers to the DB of another platform.

- Is this possible?
- Is there any other possible way?

Comment: Do you mean Liferay Forms (or custom implemented forms)? Liferay Forms can be yet connected to Workflows and one step can be to send data to an external system (custom Code) or you can hook into by implementing a @Component for `service=MVCActionCommand.class` with `mvc.command.name=/form/submit` and handle submitted data by your own

Comment: Yes, I'm using Liferay Forms. I want to send the form answers to an external system, but I don't know how to get those answers and send them to the external system on one step of the WorkFlow. Is there any way for submitting the form directly to the external system? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Liferay Forms also support the concept of a StorageType. Please check this [Developer Guide](https://learn.liferay.com/dxp/latest/en/process-automation/forms/developer-guide/writing-a-form-storage-adapter.html).
Please search for the `_saveFile` where form data was serialized and written to a file. In your case, you need a ServiceClient which can be (in the easiest case) just a Http POST request. If you have java11 or above, there are simple examples about post request (https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html)

Comment: I suppose that for using _saveFile I'll need to develop a portlet. I was looking for something like this: https://gist.github.com/jverweijL/09c20f69c763c1681dfb3a1084b4c94f. I tried with that workflow example, but my Mockbin is not reporting any GET/POST request. Any idea?

Comment: you don't need a portlet, but a osgi module with a DDMStorageAdapter implementation. But is also fine to send your data as part of the workflow as described in the gist - if this fits your needs